# How to find out if I can remove a startup program (AwaySch) from XP

Tags: windows-xp, startup

I am having a problem with the program AwaySch.exe, which comes with the ThinkPad suite on my T61; on shutdown, there is always an error message which must be manually closed.

How can I find out whether the program is necessary (eg for the rest of the ThinkVantage suite), or whether it is ok simply to remove it from startup?  Thanks!

----Edit

I know *how* to remove it; what I want to find out is whether removing it will defrost my fridge and format my hard drive :)

Comment: I just wanted to make clear, why I voted "close" on this question. The FAQ: "Please note that Server Fault is not for general computer troubleshooting questions; if you paid for that desktop hardware, and it's your personal workstation, it is unlikely that your question is appropriate for Server Fault. " -- Sorry.

Comment: Well, its my work laptop, bought by the company... does that count?

Answer (score 2):

Answer for you in german:
Die Datei AwaySch.EXE befindet sich in einem Unterordner von "C:\Program Files". Bekannte Dateigrößen unter Windows XP sind 69632 bytes (83% aller Vorkommen), 91688 bytes.
Das Programm ist nicht sichtbar. Das Programm startet wenn Windows startet (siehe Registry Schlüssel: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run). Diese Datei wird vom Betriebssystem Windows nicht benötigt. Deshalb bewerten wir diese Datei zu 46% als gefährlich, aber vergleichen Sie diese Wertung mit den Mitglieder Meinungen.

Hinweis: Viren und andere schädliche Dateien können sich als AwaySch.EXE tarnen. Insbesondere, wenn sich die Datei in C:\Windows oder C:\Windows\System32 Ordner befindet. Bitte kontrollieren Sie deshalb, ob es sich bei dem Prozess AwaySch.EXE auf Ihrem PC um einen Schädling handelt. Möchten Sie die Sicherheit Ihres PCs überprüfen, so empfehlen wir Ihnen die Software Security Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

try: start->execution->msconfig
     uncheck the related line in the start tab

Answer (score 0):

Startup->Run->msconfig->Start
Then you just have to click on AwaySch.exe to remove it from the Startup programlist.
After rebooting, just check the box under the text you'll get and click OK!

Answer (score 0):

Win+R, msconfig.exe
or
technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx